# group function in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I need help with a little problem in XSLT

I have a XML :
a.xsm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExtData>
  <table bName="B SERs" id="BSER">
    <Col bName="Bus" id="BUS">
      <CoreCol coreEName="SER" coreHref="../_a2.xml" corebName="Bus" coreId="BUS"/>
    </Col>
    <Col bName="Bus" id="BUS">
      <CoreCol coreEName="MOR" coreHref="../_a5.xml" corebName="Busw" coreId="BUSW"/>
    </Col>
    <Col bName="Ser" id="NAME">
      <CoreCol coreEName="SER" coreHref="../_a2.xml" corebName="Ser" coreId="NAME"/>
    </Col>
    <Col bName="ID" id="ID">
      <CoreCol coreEName="SER" coreHref="../_a2.xml" corebName="SerId" coreId="UCMDB_ID"/>
    </Col>
  </table>
</ExtData>
```

I need write a function that by coreName return coreHref
It's mean :: 
my_variable = same_func("SER")  ==>> variable will be "../_a2.xml"

thank for help!

Comment: This is a good example how a question should *not* be written. It isn't clear what is wanted. The question talks about `coreName` but the XML document doesn't contain any element or attribute named "coreName". Even if we somehow guess that you mean "coreEName", in the provided XML document there isn't a 1:1 mapping between the value of a "coreEname" attribute and a (single) value of a "coreHref" attribute. -1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is XPath expression to select coreHref:

```
//Col/CoreCol[@coreEName='YorName']/data(@coreHref)
```

Comment: Hi Sergey. thanks for answer, but it doesn't work me :(

Comment: @Vikonto - Did you change `YorName` to `SER`?

Comment: :) I change it , but it still don't work :(

Comment: Make sure you use the proper register, SER and Ser are different things. I have checked my answer and it is works

Comment: Oh sorry, I have wrote coreName instead of coreEName. Now is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Define a key

```
<xsl:key name="by-name" match="Col/CoreCol" use="@coreEName"/>
```

then use it with e.g. `key('by-name', 'SER')/@coreHref`.

But note that inside of `xsl:function` you don't have a context node to apply the key function with two arguments, thus if you want to use the approach inside of an `xsl:function` make sure you have

```
<xsl:variable name="main-root" select="/"/>
```

as a global variable and then use `key('by-name', 'SER', $main-root)/@coreHref`.